# Shapefiles with same coordinate system do not match

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, shapefile

I have a problem with ArcGIS. I'd like to project two layers in the same coordinate system (WGS84/Mercator; 3395) but these don't match.

I have one map with sovereign states borders, drawn from Nüssli EurAtlas data. The spatial reference system for all layers in this dataset is the world Mercator projection of World Geodetic System (WGS84).

Additionally, I have data on pogroms with latitude and longitude, drawn from Koyama (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/ecoj.12331).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to project the pogroms point layer and project these points on the Nüssli map. I have "implemented" two strategies to do so:

1. I started by projecting the map shapefile in WGS84/Mercator, and then projected the points (pogroms) layers, by adding data XY, specifying the latitude and longitude of the excel file, and finally defining 3395 as the coordinate system.
2. Given that this turned out not working, I tried something different. I projected both of these shapefiles in Europe Lambert Conformal Conic, before adding a new dataframe and then inserting the two shapefiles in Lambert coordinates. And the shapefiles keep not matching.

Here is a snapshot of the pogroms data. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Web Mercator and WGS84 decimal degrees are not the same coordinate systems. 3395 is built upon 4326, but they are in no way equivalent.  You simply need to project your geographic CS data.  Please [Edit] your question to detail **exactly** how you are going about reprojection, and the problem should be simple enough to find.

Comment: Stop at 1. You should have defined the points to be 4326, since they are **not** 3395. I realize it seems a bit odd, but [please refrain from thanks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in GIS SE. "Thanks in advance" is viewed as aggressive and/or manipulative, and will *reduce* participation.